# how to call function and access in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to show data which stored in DB at update page.
My problem is that I wanna access innerHTML tag to show images and any other data like

```
document.getElementById(visibilities).checked = true;
```

or

```
for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = files[i];
                image.height = 100;
                display.appendChild(image); 
            }
```

Btw, I don't know how to access tags or call function with onload in innerHTML. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
function getData(id) {
    var path  = '/project/update/' + id;

    restfull.get({
        path: path
    }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) return;
        var title = data.title;
        var descriptions = data.descriptions;
        var visibilities = data.visibilities;
        var files = data.image;
        
    
        
        const modal =  new window.Modal({
            modalContainerId: 'updateModal'
            , modalTitleText: `Update Your Project`
            , modalContentsInnerHTML: ` <form method="put" id="updateform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onload='getData()'>
          <input type="radio" name="visibilities" value="public" id="public">Public
          <input type="radio" name="visibilities" value="private" id="private">Private
          <input type="radio" name="visibilities" value="unlisted" id="Unlisted">Unlisted <br>
          <label for="title">Project Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required value="${title}"><br>
          <label for="descriptions">Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="descriptions" id="descriptions" required value="${descriptions}"><br>
          <label for="multi_image">Images/ Videos
          <input type="file" id="multi_image" name="multi_image" multiple onchange='previewImages()'><br>
          <div id="display"></div>
          <div id="projectpreview"></div>
          
        </form>`
            , modalSubmitBtnText: 'Update'
            , modalSubmitBtnAction: function(){updatesubmit(data._id)}
            , modalCancelBtnText: 'Cancel'     
            , modalCancelBtnAction: function() {
                modal.destroy();
            }
        })
        modal.show();
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to clarify your question. I think I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function outside and reference it by name. Here I also use the dataset of the button inside the innerHTML to store the id I want to access when the function is called.

```js
const id = 1

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = `
  <button data-selected="${id}" onclick="foo(event)">Click Me</button>
`

const foo = ({target}) => console.log('selected id:', target.dataset.selected)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to preview the uploaded image for update:**

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}

$("#imgInput").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInput" />
  <img id="preview" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

**If you want to display an already stored image from database:**

```js
var image = document.getElementById('preview');
    
image.src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==";
    
image.width=100;
image.height=100;
image.alt="here should be some image";
```

```html
<img id="preview">
```